# unable to destroy tkinter window on mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am using below code to create a tkinter window and then close the window after clicking on ok button. my code runs perfectly on windows and linux os but on mac os after clicking on the ok button the root window doesn't disappear and remains as long as the python terminal is open. i tried using root.quit() method but i am getting same issue.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def show_popup(test):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.title(test)
    
    out = {}
    def sel_yes():
        root.destroy()
        out.update({"result": "yes"})
        
    def sel_no():
        root.destroy()
        out.update({"result": "no"})

    btn_yes = Button(root, text = 'YES', bd = '8', command = sel_yes).place(x=20, y=100)
    ben_no = Button(root, text = 'NO', bd = '8', command = sel_no).place(x=130, y=100)
    
    root.mainloop()
    return out


result = show_popup("testing")
print(result)

time.sleep(30)
```

this function is part of a larger program where the return value from tkinter is used later in the program.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX with python 3.8.4. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley sorry i forgot to mention that the code runs properly while using in a py file. but my use case requires me to use this inside a function as the return from tkinter will be used in later parts of the program. here i have given a time.sleep where the window gets closed only after 30 seconds sleep. instead of getting destroyed at roo.destroy(). the same code runs perfectly fine in windows and linux problem occurs only in mac. i am using python 3.8.5 but i also tried on 3.8.4 and other versions problem remains same. thanks for the response. i have updated the question.